# when page postback occure, page in iframe reload again

Tags: iframe, postback, reload

I have an aspx page: Main.aspx which has several components that cause
a postback. In the page Main.aspx I also have an iframe which contains
a multi-page pdf file.

The problem I am facing is that whenever the user does an action which
causes a postback on the main page Main.aspx, the page posts back and
the pdf file in the iframe is reloaded. This is a problem becuase if
the user has rotated or magnified the page then that is lost.

Is there anyway that the content in the iframe is not refreshed?

Comment: I don't think so. You could reload the other part of the page dynamically through Ajax. Or place it in another IFrame which is being postbacked.

Comment: I have a link button in grid column in main page. when link button clicked, cause a postback in main page. in server side a dynamic javascript for window.open() for link is created and register in page.if main page not post back on link click,how i create the link address for window.open. I need to open a pop up window when link button is clicked.